# How to disable default browser navigation with Space in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, keyboard-shortcuts

I have defined a keyboard shortcut that uses space. After I have pressed the shortcut two things happen: some random navigation in my app and also the code in my eventHandler from the keyboard shortcut.

I found [THIS](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm) table with browser keyboard shortcuts and obviously space sometimes is used for navigation. So is there a way to stop the navigation with space in Flex, because eating the spacebar button doesn't seem to work:

```
  FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,
                                                     ignoreSpaceNavigation);

  private static function ignoreSpaceNavigation(event:KeyboardEvent):
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
```

So any ideas how to stop the navigation? (I really want to use space for that keyboard shortcut!)

Comment: Probably navigation starts before event handling. In this case you stop propagation after navigation happens.
Try to set priority to your handler:
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ignoreSpaceNavigation, false, 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set event listener on a stage and use capture

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ignoreSpaceNavigation, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Any idea why it didn't work with FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener...?