# Spark Button trapping keydown (spaceBar) event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

**Update:** Apparently this is part of the [accessibility scheme of Flex Spark Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7da6.html)

> **Button control** Press the Spacebar to activate the Button control. To cancel activating a button, press the Tab key to move the focus off
>   the Button control before releasing the Spacebar.

I guess it can be turned off through compiler directives: [Accessibility best practices](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/best-practices.html)

---

**Question:** Is there any reason a Spark Button would trap key events, in particular a "spacebar" key event?

**Background:** I've inherited and am maintaining a large legacy project done in Flex 4.6. I am seeing a weird behavior with a `Spark Button`. Essentially, once the button has been clicked on (i.e. given focus) a keyEvent (spaceBar) will trigger the click event handler attached to the button.

Weird, right?

The button is defined in `MXML` (below) within an `MX:Module`. The module has key event listeners attached to the stage but the event handlers for those do nothing with the button:

```
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, echoKeyDownHandler);
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, echoKeyUpHandler);
```

If I put a trace statement in the button's event handler to check the event type when this weird behavior occurs, the type is reported as a `click`. I don't see anything in the docs for the [Spark Button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html) about capturing key events like this.

```
   <s:Button id="toggleBtn"
     label="Editor" 
     click="toggleBtn_clickHandler(event)" 
      x="943" y="8"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite normal with Flex. You should also be able to navigate through the interactive elements by using the `<tab>` key. `<space>` usually acts like a click. You could try to avoid this by either

a) set the focus to another object after pressing the button

or

b) by checking the **keyboardPressed** property.

Both is a bit hacky imho. I am not sure if it is possible to turn of keyboard navigation completely in Flex.

[edit 1] I am just thinking if it wouldn't help to simply overwrite the default keyboard handler like this:

```
override protected function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {}
```

this is inherited by UIComponent. and you would need to create an own component extending s:Button. A little drawback...

[edit 2] I wasn't able to stop thinking about that, even I stopped using Flex 2-3 years ago. So I googled a bit and found this stack overflow post:
[How to disable default browser navigation with Space in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205150/how-to-disable-default-browser-navigation-with-space-in-flex)

Comment: oh, yes, `keyboardPressed` is protected, so it would only work inside a custom component extending s:Button - my fault.

Comment: Not 100% related to your problem, but also check the properties **tabEnabled** and **tabFocusEnabled**. So you can get at least rid of <tab> navigation. I guess Adobe dropped Flex with a reason ;-)